# Perl - filtering array elements using grep with multiple conditions

Tags: perl

I am trying to filter values in an array using grep (in Perl).
My goal is to remove array elements where both the "pending" element is INVALID_APNS and the "token" element is empty

This does not work - it deletes everything. The array contains 0 elements after the rep, but should contain 2.

```
use constant INVALID_APNS => -1;
@active_connections = (
    {
        pending => INVALID_APNS,
        token=>'123'
    },
    {
        pending => INVALID_APNS,
        token=>'123'
    },
    {
        pending => INVALID_APNS,
        token=>''
    },


);
 @active_connections = grep { ($_->{pending} != INVALID_APNS) && ($_->{token} ne '')} @active_connections;
 print scalar @active_connections;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude records with `$_->{'pending} == INVALID_APNS && $_->{'token'} eq ''`, you are negating that improperly to get what grep should include.  Either of these should do what you want:

```
! ( $_->{'pending'} == INVALID_APNS && $_->{'token'} eq '' )
```

or

```
$_->{'pending'} != INVALID_APNS || $_->{'token'} ne ''
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Thanks - I seem to have a brain-freeze at the moment. Your solution works - I don't get why mine is wrong. I'll re-look at this tomorrow morning with some strong coffee and once I get it, I'll mark it as resolved. Thank you!

Comment: @user1361529 the opposite of "it's big AND it's red" is "it's not big OR it's not red".

Comment: Right. I'm an idiot. I can't believe I spent all day on this. Thank you